# Azure Sphere (Seeed Studio) updated to 20.01 but now can not enable developer mode

Tags: azure-sphere

I moved my device to retail eval for 20.01 but now can not deploy an app from Visual Studio 2019.

When I run

azsphere device enable-development

output is (note id's have deliberately been corrupted for posting here):

Getting device group 'Development' for product 'MyProduct'.
Device ID: '3EA5EF04079999999999999999999999999999999999999247A0BC6D3702B776291F647A96B8183CE07C1817D02CDD95B0D8B8E5428D1A201A8C34137935'
Downloading device capability configuration.
Setting device group to 'Development' with ID '9fc999999994a76-8982-50c4da0278c8'.
Successfully disabled application updates.
Enabling application development capability on attached device.
Applying device capability configuration to device.
error: The device did not accept the device capability configuration. Please check the Azure Sphere OS on your device is up to date using 'azsphere device show-deployment-status'.
When I do:

azsphere device show-deployment-status

C:\WINDOWS\system32>azsphere device show-deployment-status
Your device is running Azure Sphere OS version 20.01.
The Azure Sphere Security Service is targeting this device with Azure Sphere OS version 19.11.
warn: Your device is running an older Azure Sphere OS version (20.01). It has not yet started receiving the available update to version 19.11.
warn: Your device is connected to Wi-Fi. If the over-the-air update does not begin, reset your device and try again.
Go to aka.ms/AzureSphereUpgradeGuidance for further advice and support.
What do I need to do to unlock the device?

Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a colleague helped me figure out the solution and I have written it up at https://github.com/gloveboxes/Enabling-Developer-Mode-on-Azure-Sphere-20.01

Cheers Dave